# Is there any object in `JavaScript` that is similar to `application` object in `JAVA Servlet`

Tags: javascript, node.js, servlets

I'm a fresh man in `Node.js` and during these days I had participated in project that needed to provide user a online-chatting panel.

In my project, I integrated partial of the `Think JS` framework(Mainly related to the `socket.io`) ,which is actually based on `KOA`. While I was trying to store the collection or list of online user with the function `session(variable 
 name, variable value )`, I found out that this session might be refreshed and variables were all be initialized if I refresh the page(this session seemed to be reallocated).

But the `session` **should be held before the browser has been closed**.

So my questions are:

1. While we are using the session to store something, would the session be reallocated if we are trying to refresh the page?(not close or changed the browser)
2. Is there any solution(except writing the data into the exterior file like `.xml` or database) that can help me to store the data more easily?(something useful like the `application` object in `JAVA Servlet`)

Project Environment :

- *Think JS V3.2.10*
- *Node.JS v11.7.0*

Comment: Are you asking how to manage a session in node? Really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Emm...I want to know whether the session in node would be changed if we refresh the page and how to store the data that should be shared to multiple session(different client) with node

Comment: Session cookies? How most apps deal with sessions. Or cookieless session?

Comment: `Cookies` can solve it but it's not save right? I mean, it's stored in client browser and is visible to user.The data I want to store in session is the list of online-users that it should be private to primary client

Comment: Sorry I'm just a student, maybe my comments are just too immature.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session or many other libraries out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,After reading the material of `THINK JS`, I finally solve my second problem with function `cache()` as it provide the way to store data that is visible to each session in server.

Here is the link to the guidance: [Click](https://thinkjs.org/en/doc/3.0/cache.html)